# Help On SOQL Statment

Tags: soql, community

I have 3 objects (CBR__c, Account, AccountTeamMember).  CBR__c and AccountTeamMember are both Child objects to Account.

Here are the fields I'm trying to retrieve:

```
CBR__c.Id,
CBR__c.Account_Name__r.Id (Lookup to Account),
Account.Id,
AccountTeamMember.UserId,
```

From record Id in **CBR__c object**, I'm trying to retrieve UserId from **AccountTeamMember** object.

Here is what I have so far and it's giving me an error:

```
select Id, Account_Name__r.id, (select AccountTeamMember.UserId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId = '0017000000f3mKm' and TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Engineer') from CBR__c Where Id = 'a5b180000008Ocn'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go up to the parent and then down to the children again in one single query. You'll have to split that and do 2 separate queries:

```
CBR__c cbr = [SELECT Id, Account__c FROM CBR__c WHERE Id = 'a5b180000008Ocn'];

List <AccountTeamMember> teamMembers = [SELECT AccountTeamMember.UserId FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountId = :cbr.Account__c and TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Engineer'];
```

Alternatively, if you go from the Account then you can include both child objects:

```
Account account = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM CBRS__r), (SELECT Id, UserId FROM AccountTeamMembers WHERE TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Engineer') FROM Account WHERE Id = '0017000000f3mKm'];
```

Where `CBRS__r` is the child relationship name (I'm just guessing here but you can confirm if you check the `Account__c` lookup on the `CBR__c` object). Then you can access the list of `CBR__c` and `AccountTeamMember` records related to the account by:

`account.CBRS__r` - which is a `List <CBR__c>` records

`account.AccountTeamMembers` which is a `List <AccountTeamMember>` records

Note: `Account__r.Id` is equivalent to `Account__c`

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative solution should you require a single line query.

Comment: I see, I think it is best to keep them separated because fields from CBR__c can be edited by users, while fields from AccountTeamMember are ready only.